# model.matrix and makeContrasts in R

Tags: r, matrix, bioinformatics, bioconductor, contrast

I would like to do some contrasts via linear regression modeling in R. I have the following data, `mat1`:

```
   Gene1    Gene2   Gene3
1  5.89     7.45    2.66
2  8.99     5.39    1.58
3  3.67     6.88    4.82
4  8.25     8.76    3.58
```

I use the following code to create a design matrix:

```
library(limma)
expression <- factor(mat1)
design <- model.matrix(~0 + expression)
colnames(design) <- levels(expression)
```

The design matrix looks now very strange. And the number of rows and columns has changed. Where is the mistake?

Here is the next chunk of code I would like to go on with:

```
fit <- lmFit(mat1, design)
contrast.matrix <- makeContrasts(Gen1 - Gen2, levels = design)
fit2 <- contrasts.fit(fit, contrast.matrix)
fit2 <- eBayes(fit2)
```

Is that the right way? Maybe anybody could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Try to give an example to us.

Comment: Normally you make a contrast of conditions not genes. `expression <- factor(mat1)` does is not correct, it should probably be `factor(rownames(mat1)` or `factor(colnames(mat1)` depending on what you are constrasting.

Answer (score 1):

your general syntax of analyzing gene expression using linear model looks correct, including the `contrast.matrix`. However, it concerns me that your code doesn't provide information on sample features (aka clinical covariates in patient studies). I am not sure what the **question/hypothesis** that you are testing is. For example, if you are comparing treatment (usually coded with `1`) versus no treatment (`0`), you would run:

```
design <- model.matrix( ~ feature$treatment)
```

where `feature` is a matrix or data.frame with clinical information.

Without having seen your actual data and sample/clinical features, my best guess is that something went wrong in these two lines of code:

```
design <- model.matrix(~0 + expression)
colnames(design) <- levels(expression)
```

That is, the set up of the design matrix.

You may want to revisit the `limma` R/Bioconductor package and work through an example, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
fit <- lmFit(mat1, design)
contrast.matrix <- limma::makeContrasts(Gen1 - Gen2, levels = design)
fit2 <- limma::contrasts.fit(fit, contrast.matrix)
fit2 <- eBayes(fit2)
```

Comment: This looks exactly (AFAICS) like the code posted by the OP.  Can you explain how this solves the problem/answers the question?

Comment: @BenBolker: It's not _exact_; this contributor adds the `limma::` prefix to their calls to `makeContrasts()` and `contrasts.fit()`. I'm not familiar enough with R to know if this is a _meaningful_ change or not, but it is at least a slight difference. Regardless, if that's the issue, it'd be useful for the contributor to call that out, and ideally explain _why_ it is necessary to resolve this issue.

Comment: Unless there is another package masking `limma`, that shouldn't make any difference.-